# How to check RAM timings in linux?

Tags: linux, memory

In windows, CPUz provides info about memory timings. Is it possible to view that in linux? Is there any app that can show me the memory timings of the RAM currently installed in my system?

EDIT: I want to know the CAS latency. CPUz screenshot:

[image]

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92037/how-to-view-rams-spd-timings-table

Answer (score 23):

Memtest will show you the timings and I found on the [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1007038) that i2c-tools will give you what you're looking for with these commands:

```
sudo modprobe eeprom    
decode-dimms
```

Comment: Does this work with SO-DIMM memories? It does not work on my laptop

Comment: Doesn't work on my Vaio VPCEB3M1E either.

Comment: Doesn't work on my Lenovo B70-80. Maybe need to modprobe?

Comment: There is a detailed explanation of how to get RAM specs in Linux here:
https://damieng.com/blog/2020/02/08/ddr4-ram-spd-linux

Comment: (The abovementioned article is now at https://damieng.com/blog/2020/02/08/ddr4-information-in-linux/)

Answer (score 14):

You can get information about the memory with:

```
lshw -C memory
```

In particular, you can get the clock speed and latency with:

```
lshw -C memory | grep clock
```

Comment: I get 1.9 ns. How do I translate that to CAS latency value, if possible?

Comment: If you are going to need more information, you should use [i2c-tools](http://www.richud.com/wiki/Ubuntu_See_Live_RAM_Timings_Decode_DIMMS) instead.

Comment: That 1.9 ns is the clock interval, not the latency. This tool is reading DMI, you'd need something that reads SPD.

Comment: The tool actually reports memory capabilities, not the effective clock. For instance, on my hardware (motherboard supports memory clock up to 1600 MHz) it reports: `clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)` (which is the maximum speed my DDR modules can operate at, provided they're plugged in a more modern MB).

Comment: Does this command works under virtual machine? I got nothing after executing the command

Comment: for soldered RAM (like LPDDR3) this works much better than `decode-dimms`. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me:

```
sudo aptitude install i2c-tools
sudo modprobe eeprom
sudo modprobe at24
sudo modprobe i2c-i801
sudo modprobe i2c-amd-mp2-pci
sudo modprobe ee1004
decode-dimms
```

`decode-dimms` needs the correct module to be loaded to be able to read the DIMMs. It is unclear to me exactly which one worked for me, but I guess it depends on the chipset in your machine.

Comment: Can you please add a source/ give explanation of what those commands do? Your answer appeared on the Low Quality Posts queue.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-get install i2c-tools
sudo modprobe eeprom
decode-dimms

# lots of output, including:
Decoding EEPROM: /sys/bus/i2c/drivers/eeprom/0-0050
Guessing DIMM is in                              bank 1
...
---=== Timings at Standard Speeds ===---
tCL-tRCD-tRP-tRAS as DDR3-1600                   11-11-11-28
tCL-tRCD-tRP-tRAS as DDR3-1333                   9-9-9-24
tCL-tRCD-tRP-tRAS as DDR3-1066                   7-7-7-19
tCL-tRCD-tRP-tRAS as DDR3-800                    6-6-6-14
```

*TL;DR*

Note: this is a working (on my system) guide made from analogous QA https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92037/how-to-view-rams-spd-timings-table, mostly info was mentioned here already, but "Ubuntu" link is not working, so I decided to write my own answer.

Some "discovery mission" where it is probably all started: http://www.richud.com/wiki/Ubuntu_See_Live_RAM_Timings_Decode_DIMMS

```
$ decode-dimms

Command 'decode-dimms' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install i2c-tools

$sudo apt-get install i2c-tools
$ decode-dimms
No EEPROM found, try loading the eeprom or at24 module
```